# Are there any ensembles that try to play as broad of styles of music as possible?

Tags: classical-music

The Ensemble InterContemporaine plays contemporary classical music, countless orchestras play classical music, there are groups that play Chinese, Indian, Gamelan, jazz, and so on. Is there any established institution or group of musicians that tries to have as diverse as possible a program of music they play, including jazz, gamelan, rock, contemporary classical, classical, gospel, and so on?